# Discord JS join to voice channel at specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I know my code look like sh*t but im new im nodejs  i don't know why my code is not work correctly (bot join to voice channel, **theoretically**  is playing a music but practically no)
code:

```
while (true)
{
 d = new Date();
 currtime = d.getHours() * 100 + d.getMinutes();
 console.log(currtime);
 if (currtime == 1912 && loop == true)
 {
  loop = false;
  console.log("21:37");
  const connection =   await client.channels.cache.get(VOICECHANNEL).join(); 
  connection.play(LINK, { volume: VOLUME }); // link = url (mp3)
  setTimeout(() => {  client.channels.cache.get(VOICECHANNEL).leave();},204000);  // 204000 = length of the song
 }
 else 
 {
  sleep(204000);
  loop = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TcUJybDC - code "(bot join to voice channel, theoretically is playing a music but practically no)" - i mean i don't hear the song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here are a few issues that I can see.

First, you are not waiting for your sleep() function, so your loop will execute as fast as possible, over and over again.

Second, after you are waiting for your sleep(), it is currently set to sleep for 204 seconds, but you are checking to see if curtime is **exactly** the target time, rather than greater than.you either need to reduce the sleep time, or change the if statement (or both).

I cant debug your discord code, as I dont know the syntax, but this should at least get you started.

```
const targetTime = 1326;

    while (true) {
        d = new Date();
        currtime = d.getHours() * 100 + d.getMinutes();
        console.log(currtime);
        if (currtime >= targetTime && currtime < targetTime + 1) {
            //const connection = await client.channels.cache.get(VOICECHANNEL).join();
            console.log('connected');
            //connection.play(LINK, { volume: VOLUME }); // link = url (mp3)
            //setTimeout(() => { client.channels.cache.get(VOICECHANNEL).leave(); }, 204000);  // 204000 = length of the song
            break;
        }
        else {
            console.log('sleep')
            await sleep(60000);
            loop = true;
        }
    }
```

It may also be worth looking into something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Which is optimized for scheduling tasks.